# XPath (SOAP UI): check if a specific namespace URI is defined

Tags: xpath, soapui

I'm trying to write an assertion for a test step in SOAP UI using an XPath Match assertion. 
I want to check if a specific namespace URI is defined in the a REST service's response. 
I'm trying to use a combination of `in-scope-prefixes` and `namespace-uri-for-prefix` functions, but I can't make it work, so maybe somebody has an advice.

```
in-scope-prefixes(/other:element)
```

gives me a collection containing all defined prexies, I cant output it with

```
string-join(in-scope-prefixes(/other:element), ',')
```

So in a frist step I want to want to select the prefix of the namespace URI I'm looking for with

```
in-scope-prefixes(/other:element)[namespace-uri-for-prefix(.,/my:rootElement)='http://namespaceuri.org/my']
```

But SOAP UI gives me the error

> Invalid XPath expression

Now I wonder if that expression is really invalid? Something like

```
in-scope-prefixes(/other:element)[concat(.,'-') = 'my-']
```

works without raising an error.
Am I missing something?

**EDIT1**
I just realised that I'm able to achieve what I want using *XQuery* with

```
declare namespace other='http://namespaceuri.org/other';
let $rt := /other:rootElement
let $ret := exists(in-scope-prefixes($rt)[namespace-uri-for-prefix(.,$rt)='http://namespaceuri.org/my'])
return $ret
```

But this will not work:

```
declare namespace other='http://namespaceuri.org/other';
let $ret := exists(in-scope-prefixes(/other:rootElement)[namespace-uri-for-prefix(.,/other:rootElement)='http://namespaceuri.org/my'])
return $ret
```

For the latter, SOAP UI gives the exception

> Invalid XQuery expression

It seems the behaviour is identical to XPath, except that I can use variables in XQuery.
Does that make sense to anyone? Any idea how to get that working with XPath?